# How can I add value in different variable after clicking “+”?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add value in different variable after clicking “+”?

```
document.querySelector('.buttons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var selectednumber = targetElement.dataset.number;
  var element = document.getElementById('display');

  element.value += selectednumber;
  oldvalue = element.value;
  console.log("in old :" + oldvalue);

  if (targetElement.dataset.number === '+') {
    //after click of +
    var element = document.getElementById('display');

    newvalue = oldvalue;
    console.log("i ma new " + newvalue);
    console.log(newvalue);
  }

  if (targetElement.dataset.number === "=") {
    sum = oldvalue + newvalue;
```

Comment: What do you even mean?...

Comment: event i need to add value in old and new value i.e old+ new but old value remain in varible

Comment: And how does your question relate to the code you posted? Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], along with a specific description of your problem, your current result and your desired result.

Comment: So just do `oldvalue += value + value` or whatever you want to add to the old value. Or use `oldvalue = value` to throw away the old value and set it to something new. I dont get what the problem is, as far as i can tell you're asking how to set values in javascript, which is really so basic you should already know how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Add a Click Listener for the **+** button and on there, use this line of code:

```
value += 50;
```

**Remember**, next time you ask a question, please clarify what you need to happen.

Hope this answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

Make the "+" a button then when the button will be clicked you just add those value getting from  element or if you want the button to be `+` sometimes and `=` sometimed then change the button value of its inner html value according to that and do 
`let action = document.getElementById(id).value`
Or 
`let action  = document.getElementById(id).innerhtml`
And put the `action` in a if condition